# How is it possible that $().css doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, css

Please Look at the following code as it runs in console:

```
$('#adBlock').css('text-align');
> undefined
$
> function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}
$('#adBlock')
> n.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#adBlock"}
$('#adBlock').css('text-align', 'left !important');
> [prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "#adBlock div"]
$('#adBlock').css('text-align');
> undefined
```

As you can see, JQuery is defined and element id 'adBlock' exists. I can make CSS attribute 'text-align' to be 'left !important'. If so, why do I get 'undefined' when I type:

```
$('#adBlock').css('text-align')
```

?

Comment: Are you sure the element exists? jQuery will always return a jQuery object, even if no object exists. However, if one exists, you'll find entries in the object.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Are you trying to output the `text-align` value?

Comment: looking to get `text-align` value?

Comment: my guess is that the element doesn't exist, too, because i don't see any `length` property in here

Comment: You're right. $('#adBlock').length returns 0. But how? I clearly see it in the DOM.

Comment: Upper/lower-case maybe? Can you show the respective part of the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#adBlock").css({'text-align':'left'})
```

You are not specifying the rest of the styling you want with the `text-align` command.

Answer (score 0):

This is used to set the CSS property to a element,

```
 $('#adBlock').css('property', 'value');
```

to get the property to **console**

```
 console.log( $('#adBlock').attr('property'));
```

EXample

```
console.log( $('#adBlock').attr('text-align'));
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to retrieve the current value of 'text-align' you need to assign it a value instead.

```
$('#adBlock').css('text-align', 'left !important');
```

Comment: Why? If OP just wants the current value, why the need to set it before?

Comment: Okay.  I guess I don't understand the original post.  It must be missing from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

This post can be closed. The problem is that the result of $('#adBlock') gave an empty array. It might be misleading, since I would expect an error.